# Why do my divs have this mysterious right margin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align divs #inner3 and #inner4 side by side, but they refuse to cooperate. When I inspect the DOM through Chrome, there is this mysterious right side margin on both divs that extends to the end of the page.

I have the global margin set to 0, but when I look deeper it says that there is *no* value for margin, period. Why?? Why won't my divs cooperate either? I have removed white space, made them smaller, floating, all to no avail. I have been searching and struggling for over 2 hours now.

Note: the overflow-x is for the animation; the background CSS is for the parallax.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0em;
}

#section2 {
  height: 500px; 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

#inner3 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#inner4 {
  height: 500px; 
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Code: https://codepen.io/hungus--bungus/pen/rdgEze?editors=1100

Page: https://codepen.io/hungus--bungus/full/rdgEze

[image: Orange portion is the UNK margin]

[image]

Photos are taken using the Chrome "Inspect" feature, and information can be found in the "Computed" tab at the bottom after selecting the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to `#inner3` and `#inner4` will put them side-by-side.

```
#inner3 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner4 {
  height: 500px; 
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hah, I swear I tried this 3 or 4 times before with no success. I tried it this time and it worked immediately. Must have had all the pieces, but not together. Thanks a TON!

Comment: Sure thing! Really like your home page so far, by the way. Cool background image.

Comment: Could you @Jake Reece please also, where does this margin comes from? I do really not understand it. Thank you very much!

Comment: The empty space isn't actually margin. (Recall in OP's question where they stated that they inspected the elements and margin had no value). The reason we see empty space is because the div is a block element. Block elements stack vertically unless you tell them to go inline.